# CentOS 7 cron jobs

Tags: centos, cron

/etc/crontab is empty yet cron jobs are still being run.  scripts that are located in /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, etc. are still being run.  So where is the master if it's not /etc/crontab?  Is this all hard coded, now?  I've been dealing with /etc/crontab in Linux for over 20 years.  I'm stumped.

Thanks,
Curtis

Answer (score -1):

From [`cron(1)`:](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html)

```
Cron searches /var/spool/cron for crontab files which are named after accounts in /etc/passwd; The found crontabs are loaded into the memory.  Cron also searches for /etc/anacrontab and any files in the /etc/cron.d directory
```

Comment: I looked in there and there are a few jobs, but the master crontab is empty and non of those jobs make reference to /etc/cron.hourly, etc.  There's nothing in systemd either. "systemctl list-timers --all" show a whole lot of nothing.

Comment: Nothing in /etc/cron.d/ ?  That’s the normal location and there should be some files there already on a default system.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's all handled by the pig known as systemd.  If I wanted a system to run like Windows, I'd run Windows.